# TextView outside of a cardView

Tags: java, android, layout, textview

i want to swap the functionality of the oldTextView to the TextView with ID nameAgeLabel.

The "nameAgeLabel" is outside of the View view.
It also should change the text dynamically like it does now, depending on the view that is currently loaded.

```
public View getView(final int position, View View, ViewGroup parent) {


    Log.d("position:",String.valueOf(position));
    Log.d("laenge user id",String.valueOf(userIds.size()));

    String currentUserId = userIds.get(position);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
            (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_single_mode_vc, parent, false);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.offer_image);
    Bitmap image = userImages.get(currentUserId);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(image);


 TextView oldTextView= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
 oldTextView.setText(userNames.get(currentUserId));
   //works fine

    return view;
}
```

my onCreate looks like this :

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_single_mode_vc);
    TextView nameAge = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameAgeLabel);

    updateImage();
    //(thats another method)

}
```

acvivity_single_mode_vc.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.daprlabs.aaron.swipedeck.layouts.SwipeFrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:swipedeck="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/swipeLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"/>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    />
<com.daprlabs.aaron.swipedeck.SwipeDeck
    android:id="@+id/swipe_deck"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="600dp"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    swipedeck:max_visible="3"
    swipedeck:card_spacing="15dp"
    swipedeck:swipe_enabled="true" >

</com.daprlabs.aaron.swipedeck.SwipeDeck>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/close"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:elevation="1dp"
    android:background="@drawable/close"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/light" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/check"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:background="@drawable/check"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/light" />

<TextView

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="350dp"
    android:id="@+id/nameAgeLabel"
    android:background="@color/separator"
   />
</com.daprlabs.aaron.swipedeck.layouts.SwipeFrameLayout>
```

content_single_mode_vc.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="25dp"
    android:clipChildren="true">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/offer_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_height="200dp"/>
<TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="137dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="137dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="222dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"/>

</RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/left_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/offer_image"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/right_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/offer_image"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

So, the main question is where and how do i have to change the textview "nameAge" to get the same result as i do now? In my getView Method doesnt work because

```
TextView nameAge= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameAgeLabel)
```

doesnt include the textView with ID "nameAgeLabel". Doing it in the onCreate doesnt make a lot of sense.
Creating a new view in my getView also doesnt work because i cannot return 2 views, and additionally i get a "android-requestlayout-improperly..:" message.

Thanks a lot.

Edit: class name + constructor

```
public class SwipeDeckAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
[...]
public SwipeDeckAdapter(LinkedList<String> data, Context context, LinkedList<String> userIds, Hashtable<String,String> userNames, Hashtable<String,String> userHashtags, Hashtable<String,Bitmap> userImages, Hashtable<String,ArrayList<String>> userAccepted) {
    this.data = data;
    this.context = context;
    this.userIds = userIds;
    this.userNames = userNames;
    this.userHashtags = userHashtags;
    this.userImages = userImages;
    this.userAccepted = userAccepted;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your description is incomplete, I try to guess.

Create an Adapter for the `SwipeFrameLayout` where you pass the `TextView` from the `Activity`. Either in the Constructor or a seperate method.

Something like

```
 public class CustomSwipeDeckAdapter extends SwipeDeckAdapter {

    private AppCompatTextView mNameAgeLabel;

    public SwipeDeckAdapter(List<String> data, Context context, AppCompatTextView textview) {
      mNameAgeLabel = textView;
      […]
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View View, ViewGroup parent) {
      […]
      mNameAgeLabel.setText();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response.  Yes i forgot to add my SwipeDeckAdapter Constructor. I edit it in the first post. Do you miss anything else? I tried it with the Constructor but after fixing the nullpointerexception because the mNameAgeLabel was null, the Usernames still arent displayed in my mNameAgeLabel. Is it possible that its not the correct context within the AppCompatTextView?